# cant establish a encrypted directory connection

Tags: windows, help

just downloaded tor on windows 10 very new to it and wont connect at all. used bridges and also used the connections like meek and others and nothing works please help. There has never been a successful connection since I downloaded the program.

```
9/6/2016 15:10:12 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:10:26 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:10:26 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:10:26 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:10:26 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2016 15:10:26 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
9/6/2016 15:10:26 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
9/6/2016 15:10:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2016 15:10:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:10:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2016 15:10:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
9/6/2016 15:12:53 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:12:53 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:12:53 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:12:53 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2016 15:13:05 PM.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host AF9F66B7B04F8FF6F32D455F05135250A16543C9 at 169.229.59.75:46328) 
9/6/2016 15:13:05 PM.000 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
9/6/2016 15:13:05 PM.000 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
9/6/2016 15:14:17 PM.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2016 15:14:17 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2016 15:14:17 PM.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Please use the Copy Tor Log To Clipboard button and add the Tor logs to your question, thanks.

Comment: And are you using Tor browser or just Tor?

Comment: I'm using the tor browser in the file named firefox every time I try to connect it says 

Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 169.229.59.75:46328).

Comment: well I tried every one of the different options where obfs3 is and nine of those let me connect and when I try and add bridges one at a time or 3 at a time they don't work

Comment: Removed answer because apparently it's not the issue.